# cakephp: group by is missing from generated query

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a simple model where I would like to find some count data per date.
I made this find in order to do that:

```
$statsubscriptions = $this->Nlist->Statsubscription->find('all',
    array(
     'fields'=>array('Statsubscription.date','Statsubscription.type','COUNT(*) as qs'),
     'qroup'=>array('Statsubscription.date','Statsubscription.type'),
     'conditions'=>array('Statsubscription.nlist_id'=>$id),
     'recursive'=>-1,
      )
 );
```

But it does not work. The generated query is the following:

```
SELECT `Statsubscription`.`date`, `Statsubscription`.`type`, COUNT(*) as qs
FROM `statsubscriptions` AS `Statsubscription`
WHERE `Statsubscription`.`nlist_id` = 1
```

GROUP BY is completly missing... Instead of the above I would like this query to be generated:

```
    SELECT `Statsubscription`.`date`, `Statsubscription`.`type`, COUNT(`Statsubscription`.`id`) as qs
    FROM `statsubscriptions` AS `Statsubscription`
    WHERE `Statsubscription`.`nlist_id` = 1
    GROUP BY `Statsubscription`.`date`, `Statsubscription`.`type`
```

How can I achieve this? And what could be the reason of the missing GROUP BY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing `qroup` instead of `group` (that's `q` instead of `g`). Which is why it doesn't work.

`P.S.: get some sleep...`

Comment: OMG, thanks a lot. You are right I'm going to sleep :) I wasted 1.5 hours and did not noticed the typo...